# Request suggestions for defining a primary key in Oracle 11g

Tags: database, database-design, oracle11g, rdbms, database-schema

All,

I [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527234/in-a-database-table-what-is-the-maximum-number-of-primary-keys) [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282787/primary-keys-in-oracle-and-sql-server) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234634/oracle-primary-keys-number-vs-number7-0#_=_) [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Oracle%20Primary%20Key%20Best) before posing my question to you.

I have a lot of programming/admin experience with other databases: MySql, MSSQL, PostGres, and the [one which will not be named](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/). I just don't have much experience with Oracle.

I was tasked with designing a few web-applications and supporting database tables.  The tables were designed using an ER diagram, and sent to the development group for implementation.  When they sent back the proposed table creation statements, I saw two things that seems wrong to me.  The primary key is `NUMBER(5)` and the sequence set the `MAXVALUE` to 99999.

I would have expected that the `MAXVALUE` would be omitted in favor of `NOMAXVALUE` Primary key column be a `NUMBER(*,0)` or a `LONG`.  Since I don't have much experience with Oracle table design, would you please offer up your advice?

Sincerely

Kristofer Hoch

***Edit***
Thank you for the information on `LONG`.  I'll make sure to use NUMBER, but I'm still unclear on the best way to define it: `NUMBER`, or `NUMBER(*,0)`, or `NUMBER(9)`, etc.

Comment: How many rows do you expect to be inserted in the lifespan of the said table?

Comment: COuld be 10s of thousands or more.  Its part of an enterprise solution for a global energy company.

Comment: Then definitely `number(5)` does not suffice as the size of the primary key. Apparently the person writing the table creation scripts had no idea about the volumn of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you: since the column is to hold a surrogate key generated from a sequence, the only possible purpose of the 5 digit limit would be to restrict the total number of rows ever allowed in the table to under 100,000 - which would seem perverse.  It certainly does not confer any performance or space efficiency advantages.  Probably it is just the default of their ERD tool's DDL generator.

Do not use `LONG`: in Oracle that is an obsolete and deprecated way of storing large text strings (for which CLOB is now preferred).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer regarding LONG.  May I have your suggestion on the Primary key column data type please?

Comment: I'd probably just go for NUMBER which allows any number.  Or you could restrict to integers e.g. NUMBER(38,0).

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I wouldn't specify the size of the number, but that may be more laziness (set it, forget it) than a good practice for design purposes.

But "long" would cause problems. In Oracle, "long" is a character data type that's being deprecated. It's not the same thing as the long data type for numbers in other languages/systems. It's tricky.

Comment: That is what I was thinking in regards to number size.